# Swift Take a Variable

Tags: swift

I want to take a variable nomeLabel in the func goToSecondView and display it on a SecondView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var nomeLabel:String!

    @IBAction func goToSecondView(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToSecondView", sender: self)
        let newButton = sender as UIButton
        nomeLabel = newButton.titleLabel!.text
        println("nomeLabel \(nomeLabel)")
    }
}
```

how can I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `prepareForSegue` where you have access to the destination view controller. Here is an example on how to do that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var newButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func goToSecondView(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToSecondView", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToSecondView" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            secondViewController.nomeLabel = self.newButton.titleLabel.text
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i want to take nomeLabel = newButton.titleLabel!.text

Comment: Create an outlet to your button and connect it in InterfaceBuilder. I have updated my answer. You should get the idea.

Comment: i have a error on secondViewController.nomeLabel = self.newButton.titleLabel.text instead first i put let newButton = sender as UIButton
        nomeLabel = newButton.titleLabel!.text